# How do I bypass Exchange 2007 SenderID Spam filtering on mail coming from a particular domain

Tags: exchange-2007, spam

I have some emails which are been deleted as spam and the AgentLog files contains the section

```
... Sender Id Agent,OnEndOfHeaders,DeleteMessage,,MissingPRA,No valid PRA,
```

I would like to configure Exchange 2007 not to reject emails from this particular domain.

I thought it was a matter of using the PowerShell command

```
Set-SenderIDConfig -BypassedSenderDomains domainname
```

but this does not seem to make any difference.

The domain in question does not have any SPF record set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've dug up a few bookmarks for this, so I could be barking up the wrong tree)

The PRA is the 'Purported Responsbile Address' https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4407. It doesn't look for that until phase 5 of the message's run through the gauntlet of IMF http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997242(EXCHG.80).aspx; and it's a preulde to the SPF check.

I've never seen it listed as 'Missing' before, since it's Microsoft's own algorithm that's responsible for determining it. Perhaps an earlier phase has already rejected all of the recipients at the SMTP stage, leaving a directionless message that gets flagged for deletion. I don't think the sender domain whitelist applies at this point, though.  If you can, try to catch a few messages from the sender as they come in and look at the SMTP conversations. Perhaps their MTA is mangling a standard header in a way that's causing this (unlikely, but it's where I'd look next).

Comment: Looks like you are barking up the right tree. The email is an automated report from a program and it looks like the FROM is set to the program name rather than a valid email address. So now, it is just a matter of getting the vendor to configure their software correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

For some multi-valued attributes, PowerShell does not have an "add" command
that adds to the list.

For such attributes, use the following commands:
$foo = get-contentfilterconfig

$foo.BypassedSenderDomains += somedomain.com

$foo | set-contentfilterconfig

To get a list of all bypassed domains:
get-ContentFilterConfig | select BypassedSenderDomains

Hope this would help you

Comment: +1 to that. Also bear in mind that the command in the original question will *overwrite* the array of domains set using this method, so be careful with your powershell...

Comment: I am aware of that issue and always check the before and after results whenever I change anything. In this case there were no pre-existing entries and the setting is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this old post while researching the same issue. Here's MS's answer:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125259%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

```
Set-SenderIDConfig -BypassedRecipients kim@contoso.com,john@contoso.com

Set-SenderIDConfig -BypassedSenderDomains fabrikam.com
```

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't help in my case where the error is `No valid PRA`. That means that Exchange can't not correctly determine the sender domain.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart the transport service before the change takes effect.

Comment: I'll try that. I should know tomorrow if it works.

Comment: Ok, I've never had any problems with adding those entries on the fly...just throwing it out there as a possible cause.

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting the transport service had no effect.